# How to run Python script from startup in Raspberry pi

Tags: python, startup, raspberry-pi4

I have tried doing in rc.local , bashrc file but rc.local not showing any log or not clear if it is running. bashrc is making the script run only when i open the terminal. I need to run without user intervention and my script involves network connection and websocket communication. So running in startup will ensure i get network? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you could make a daemon and start it after network is established

Comment: i am very new to Linux environment also , can you share an example or refer me any link to follow

Comment: Here are 5 Ways, number 4 is the daemon way: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Answer (score 1):

you can connect a LED to your raspberry pi to check weather your code is running or not

```
/home/pi/bashrc.
sudo python3 #LED file 
sudo python3 #your file name
```

this should make your code run every time the power is on its not depend that you open the terminal or not